# Tensorflow script in python 2.7?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to run this thing called [deepcolor](https://github.com/kvfrans/deepcolor) and it was made in python 2.7. But apparently tensorflow 0.12 doesn't work on python 2. How do i make it work? I've tried using python2 to python3 converter but it still ends me up with lots of syntax errors. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: "apparently tensorflow 0.12 doesn't work on python2" -- Why do you believe this? https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/0.12.0/ Shows Python2.7 as valid -- That said, this is a very old version of tensorflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm extremely new.

Comment: What I meant was, "It might be helpful to provide more details as to why you think it's not working in your question." -- Code or error snippets, verification that you're running the right python version, or installed the right version of tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this sort of thing is that you will want to use the exact software versions of everything that they used for deepcolor.  So in this case, try to figure out the exact python 2.7.x and numpy x.y and tensorflow 0.12.x that they used together.

Comment: I literally cannot find any tensorflow for python 2.x.y

Comment: 0.12 is old enough that it should work with old python.  My recommendation would be to use miniconda and make a new conda env with that python and then try to tell conda to install that version of tensorflow and see if there is a suitable set of packages in their repository

Comment: The oldest version of tensorflow 0.12 i can find is supported for python 3.5 :(

Comment: @DanielDirar There are two 0.12.X versions of tensorflow for Python 2.7 (cp27) on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/0.12.1/#history) . I don't know anaconda / miniconda that well but at least the 0.12.1 version seem to be available in their [repo](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?version=0.12.1).

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the windows version though. Guess I'll have to boot a linux.